# Hide element and prevent code manipulation from visitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I want to hide an HTML element. I was using `element.hide()` with Jquery, but now I realize that it only sets the attribute to `display:none`.  A visitor of my site could easily investigate the HTML element and remove this attribute to show the element again, can't they? I do not want that, what can I do to prevent code manipulation?

Comment: You could prevent users from requesting your website with all browsers, but the one you write yourself.
Beside that you can't.

Comment: You could try appending/removing the element, rather than just hiding/showing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this should be done by server side code not on client side.
To remove to the user a div with javascript you can detach it. Detach removes the element from the DOM but keeps it on memory:

```
p = $( "p" ).detach();
```

Later you can re-added it with

```
$('body').append(p);
```

For more see jQuery detach : 
http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: Thanks. It seems the server side code is the only way here.

Answer (score 2):

An experienced hacker can create the element himself anyway even if you have deleted it. You should check on the server side if the person is allowed to fill in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
element.remove()
```

But you have to store it something (try to deep at window? or cookie?) but it not and 100% solve - because experience client can find it anywhere, if he want. Or you can element.remove - and if you need append that element - did ajax to server and get it?)